# Getting 'text' content from all pages rendered in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a page at the URL `/about/` and at `/work/` in a Django project.  Each page has navigation which needs to show all the pages with a `top_level_nav=True`.  Each page needs to show `text` on each page.

I have successfully got all the pages listed in the navigation, but the content on the `/about/` and `/work/` pages is showing the `text` from all pages.

#### /about/ should be:

```
# nav
-About
–Work

# text
<p>This is the about page.</p>
```

#### and /work/ should be:

```
# nav
-About
–Work

# text
<p>This is the Work page.</p>
```

#### However, both the `/about/` and `/work/` pages are showing as:

```
#nav
–About
–Work

<p>This is the about page.</p>

<p>This is the Work page.</p>
```

Basically, all the text content is showing on all pages.

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from site_2015.models import Page
from site_2015.models import Home    

def home(request):
        home = get_object_or_404(Home)
        # now return the rendered template
        return render(request, 'site_2015/home.html', {'home': home})

def page(request, slug):
        # get the Page object
        pages = Page.objects.filter(top_level_nav=True).order_by('-pub_date')
        page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)
        # now return the rendered template
        return render(request, 'site_2015/page.html', {'page': pages})
        return render(request, 'site_2015/page.html', {'content': page})
```

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Home(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    header_image = models.FileField(upload_to='page/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('site_2015.views.home')


class Page(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nav_text = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    header_image = models.FileField(upload_to='page/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    top_level_nav = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('site_2015.views.page', args=[self.slug])


class HomeImg(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey('Home', related_name='images')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='page/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)


class PageImg(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey('Page', related_name='images')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='page/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
```

#### page.html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    {% for page in page %}
      <li><a href="/{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.nav_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  {% for content in page %}
    {{ content.text }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I know I shouldn't have a `for` block around `context.text`, but I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: If you run `Page.objects.filter(top_level_nav=True).order_by('-pub_date')` in the manage.py shell, do you get both text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is trying to use two `return` statements:

```
return render(request, 'site_2015/page.html', {'page': pages})
#The second will not get rendered, and content will not be available
return render(request, 'site_2015/page.html', {'content': page})
```

Instead, you want to render the dictionary as a whole

```
return render(request, 'site_2015/page.html', {'page': pages, 'content' : page })
```

And then in your template

```
<div class="content">
  {{ content.text }}
</div>
```

The context variable `content` will now be directly available in your template.

Comment: Perfect, I was worried I didn't explain it clearly enough. Thank you!!